# Big O Notation Review Questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I don't think I'm understanding Big O notation. I'm looked up its definition:

T(n) is O( f(n)) if there exists constants c, n-not > 0 such that T(n) <= f(n) for all n > n-not.

I have to make sure f(n) <= c * g(n).

I'm just not sure how to apply this to an actual problem.

For example, in this problem, where **log is base 2**:

logf(n) is O(log(g(n)))

I have to either prove the statement is correct or give a counter-example that disproves it's correct.

Based on the formula above, I started out with this:

logf(n) <= log(c*g(n))

Assuming I'm placing the constant in the correct location (I wasn't sure about that), I then do this:

logf(n) <= log(c) + log(g(n))

However, I don't know where to go from here or if this is the correct line of reasoning.

Can anyone help explain big O through the use of this problem? I've found the solution to my problem online but it doesn't explain the process clearly enough.

***EDIT***: This problem was solved below, but it's not really conducive to my learning.

Another problem from this review sheet would be this:

f(n^2) is O(g(n^2))

Like before, I do this:

f(n^2) <= c * g(n^2)

However (like before...) I cannot tell if there are functions that cause this to fail.

Comment: Without more info on f and g this is not true in general.

Comment: Yes, that was the given solution, but it doesn't really explain anything in detail.

Comment: You need to find f and g such that for every c there is n-not such that the inequality does not hold. I suppose 2^2^n and 2^n should do the trick.

Comment: Is finding something to disprove the big O problem just a matter of knowing what to look for? By that I mean recognizing what values would cause the inequality to become false?

Comment: It is a little more complicated. You need to prove that for any constant c then there exists a n sufficiently large such that the inequality does not hold.

Comment: Looking at your edit, you really need to review the whole concept. Because f=n and g=1 is a simple counter example

Comment: That's my main issue, I don't know how to prove the problems properly. Is 2^(n) = O(2^2^n)? And for the second problem I'm not sure where to start beyond f(n^2) = c * g(n^2)

Comment: Do you have a suitable link to any big O notation review site? I've been going through a lot and I don't seem to be getting any more understanding over this whole thing.